# Disapper notification dot when click and appear when browser reopened

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have one notification icon with dot.

**I want is when we click on that notification icon dot will be disappear. And again appears only when we closed or reopened browser.**

This is my code :`

```
<div class="notification">
                <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                <div class="notify-count count1 common-count" count="0">
                    <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
            </div>`
```

class of that dot is **" common-count"**

Comment: added solution @can-lee. You can test snippet running.

Answer (score 0):

Added event considering without your css. In snippet click on count it will disappear.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".common-count").click(function(){
  
     $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notification">
                <i class="fa fa-bell-o notification"></i>
                <div class="notify-count count1 common-count" count="0">
                    <div class="value">12</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: but i want is : now when i close the tab then also it would not be appear. It will be appear when browser will reopened

Comment: yes when you close browser tab also it will not appear.  try it this on browser.

Comment: not working.. it displays when page refresh and tab closed also. i want to appear only on browser reopened

Comment: `onbeforeunload` event, you can detect browser or tab close event cant differentiate both event.

Comment: https://www.medify.co.uk/    I just want like this site. please check this link and then reopened browser

Comment: this is little complicated part. i can see they trigger one beamer event in ajax call based on that they are deciding whether browser session closed or not. You required that ajax required.

Comment: can you do that ??

Comment: over stackoverflow not recommended. You have to build complex logic how they did,  here is script they are using https://pastebin.com/aTHHUaeB

Comment: without beamer it is possible??